Forces acting on a bouncing ball
I have encountered the following question while completing a multiple-choice exercise on dynamics, more specifically Newton's third law:

A ball falls vertically and bounces on the ground. The following statements are about the forces acting while the ball is in contact with the ground. Which statement is true?
(A) The force that the ball exerts on the ground is always equal to the weight of the ball.
(B) The force that the ball exerts on the ground is always equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to the force the ground exerts on the ball.
(C) The force that the ball exerts on the ground is always greater than the weight of the ball.
(D) The weight of the ball is always equal and opposite to the force that the ground exerts on the ball.

While option B is certainly true, and I am duly aware of the fact that the force exerted by the ground on the ball has to be greater than the weight for the ball to accelerate upwards and rebound, it is option C that seems unfathomable to me.
How could C be disproved? And under what circumstances would C not hold true? I have considered scenarios when the force exerted by the ground on the ball is smaller than or equal to the weight, but it seems unrealistic for the ball to accelerate downwards or continue travelling down into the earth at constant velocity, respectively.
A slight digression also engenders another question of how would the ball come to rest after several rebounds, in terms of the forces acting on the ball?

The ball is deforming, and not all parts of the ball accelerate at the same rate.

Consider when the lowest point on the ball has just made contact with the ground, or is just about to leave the ground. The contact force (of ball on ground or ground on ball) will then be very small.

Thank you! These comments are really insightful. As a student I tend to over-simplify the problem and fail to distinguish and consider separately the more nuanced points. Managed to understand why C is untrue.

We know from Newton's Third Law that the force exerted on the ground by the ball is equal in magnitude to the force exerted on the ball by the ground.  So let's look at this latter force.
Consider the period of time $\Delta t$ where the ball is in contact with the ground.  Just before the ball hits the ground, the ground exerts zero force on the ball.  The force then increases smoothly to some maximum that is (significantly) greater than the weight of the ball, and then decreases back to zero.  But because the force from the ground does not change discontinuously, there will be a period of time where the force from the ground is still less than the weight of the ball.
If you sketch out graphs of the forces on the ball as a function of time, the force of gravity would be represented by the red curve below (a negative constant, whose magnitude is the weight of the ball) while the force from the table would be represented by the blue curve.  You can see that the blue curve does in fact get greater than the weight of the ball — it has to, or the ball wouldn't be slowed down by the table.  But it cannot always be greater than the weight of the ball, because it cannot change discontinuously and it starts at zero at the moment of first contact.

Finally, to touch on your second question:  You can determine the overall change in speed $\Delta v$ of the ball during the collision by the fact that the area under each of these curves is equal to the impulse delivered ($\Delta p = \int F \, dt$.)  If the ball collides elastically with the table, then the impulse delivered will have to be equal to $\Delta v = 2 |v_0|$, where $v_0$ is the speed of the ball right before it hits the table.  However, if the collision is not elastic, then we will have $\Delta v < 2 |v_0|$, and so the positive impulse delivered by the table will be less.

Thank you so much. The elucidation on the actual question was epiphanous. Having analysed forces by means of the dangerously reductive free-body diagrams had me overlooked completely the continuous increase of the contact force.

The ball hits the floor at high speed, gets compressed and the force increases while it slows down. Soon it is at maximal compression and now starts the "spring back", pushing it up. At the very final moments of this, just before the ball leaves the floor to move up, the forces are small.
In fact, there is a continuous force function that gradually decreases in magnitude until zero. So, C is untrue.
